# How to fill data using an array?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this array:

```
var arrayAUX = [[ 13, 12,5],[ 13, 10,2],[ 13, 5,10],[ 14, 2,5],[ 14, 3,2],[ 15, 1,2]];
```

Then I fill another array using previous like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<arrayAUX.length; i++){
arrayGRAPH.push(arrayAUX[i]);
```

}

What I want is create a bubble graphic using the array, but it not works. This is how I use:

```
series: [{
        data: [
        for( var i=0; i<arrayGRAPH.length; i++){
            { x: arrayGRAPH[i][0], y: arrayGRAPH[i][1], z: arrayGRAPH[i][2] }
        }


        ]
    }]
```

But it doesn't work. How can i do this?

Comment: remove the loop from array!

Comment: still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your data

```
var arrayAUX = [[ 13, 12,5],[ 13, 10,2],[ 13, 5,10],[ 14, 2,5],[ 14, 3,2],[ 15, 1,2]];
arrayGRAPH = [];
for (var i=0; i<arrayAUX.length; i++){
        arrayGRAPH.push(arrayAUX[i]);
}
var data = [];
 for( var i=0; i<arrayGRAPH.length; i++){
           data.push( { x: arrayGRAPH[i][0], y: arrayGRAPH[i][1], z: arrayGRAPH[i][2] })
        }
```

and then set it:

```
series: [{
        data: data
    }]
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/homdn9md/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forEach` to loop array and add to your data

```js
var arrayAUX = [[ 13, 12,5],[ 13, 10,2],[ 13, 5,10],[ 14, 2,5],[ 14, 3,2],[ 15, 1,2]];
var data = {series: [{data: []}]}

arrayAUX.forEach(function(e) {
  data.series[0].data.push({ x: e[0], y: e[1], z: e[2]});
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your provided example code you can remove the `arrayGraph`array and directly create a object with the `arrayAUX` array.

```
var arrayAUX = [
  [13, 12, 5],
  [13, 10, 2],
  [13, 5, 10],
  [14, 2, 5],
  [14, 3, 2],
  [15, 1, 2]
];

var graph = [];
for (var i in arrayAUX) {
  graph.push({
    x: arrayAUX[i][0],
    y: arrayAUX[i][1],
    z: arrayAUX[i][2]
  })
}
```

assign your graph object like this:

```
series: [{
  data: graph
}]
```